# Azure B2C custom attribute/claim added to existing user directory throws error on sign in

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have a custom policy which adds a custom value, `HoldingId`, to new users who sign up ([using these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom)) as the value is passed to the policy via the token (along with `verified_email`).

I was hoping to *not* need to create a custom policy for **sign in**, so used the Azure Portal UI to create the custom attribute against the **b2c-extensions-app** application (and am using the respective *client* and *object* ids to line it up with the custom policy), and using the Portal have added this custom attribute to the **sign up/sign in** policy claims.

Using the Graph API, I have been able to successfully confirm that the custom value is saving against newly signed up users (returning as `extension_[AppId]_HoldingId`), and these new users are able to sign in subsequently without issue using the built in **sign in/sign up** policy.

However, any **users which already existed in the directory are no longer able to sign in**. Unfortunately, because it's a built-in policy, I'm not sure of a way to dig into the logs a-la *App Insights* to see what's going on.

My *suspicion* is that because these existing users don't have this custom attribute against them, the built-in **sign up/sign in** policy is attempting to get this value and failing.

Is it possible to get the built-in policies to ignore this attribute on users who don't have this attribute set, or will I need to create a custom policy to handle this scenario with a default value?

---

For context, the `HoldingId` is not required for *existing* users (application needs to be backwards compatible). *This is also my first venture into B2C, so I'm still learning many of these concepts.*

Comment: If, using the Graph API, you add the attribute to an existing user as a test (with a dummy value), can that user sign in?

Comment: No the user is still unable to sign in.

Comment: I think I've actually been a victim of a perfect storm of small issues - will provide an answer soon.